# XSL returning only XML result

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I'm attempting to use a Content Query webpart to display a calendar but instead of getting a styled result I get an XML result that looks like this:

```
<dsQueryResponse>
    <Rows>
      <result data here>
      <result data here>
      ...
    </Rows>
  </dsQueryResponse>
```

I had to export my webpart and manually edit the web part to point to the ItemStyle.xsl and ContentQueryMain.xsl since I don't have a Style Library folder for some reason.

Here is the template function that I am currently using (however the issue is the same with any template)

```
 <xsl:template name="RDHP_Events" match="Row[@Style='RDHP_Events']" mode="itemstyle">
        <xsl:param name="CurPos" />
        <xsl:param name="LastRow" /> 
        <xsl:param name="Title" /> 

        <xsl:variable name="RDHP_Title">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="RDHP_EventDate">
                <xsl:value-of select="@EventDate" />
        </xsl:variable>

          <xsl:if test="$CurPos = 1">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<div id="RDHP_Events_Cal"><img src="/sites/rd_home/PublishingImages/RDHP/RDHP_Ext_Event_Calendar.jpg" width="243" height="30" alt="R&amp;D Events Calendar" />  <div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_Row"> 
    <div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_Top_Date">DATE</div>
    <div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_Top_Event">EVENT</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      ctx = new ContextInfo();

      var existingHash = '';
      if(window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1){
        existingHash = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.indexOf("#"));
      }
      ctx.existingServerFilterHash = existingHash;
      if (ctx.existingServerFilterHash.indexOf("ServerFilter=") == 1) {
        ctx.existingServerFilterHash = ctx.existingServerFilterHash.replace(/-/g, '&').replace(/&&/g, '-');
        var serverFilterRootFolder = GetUrlKeyValue("RootFolder", true,ctx.existingServerFilterHash);
        var currentRootFolder = GetUrlKeyValue("RootFolder", true);
        if("" == serverFilterRootFolder && "" != currentRootFolder)
        {
          ctx.existingServerFilterHash += "&RootFolder=" + currentRootFolder;
        }
        window.location.hash = '';
        window.location.search = '?' + ctx.existingServerFilterHash.substr("ServerFilter=".length + 1);
      }

          ctx.listBaseType = 0;

      ctx.NavigateForFormsPages = false;
      ctx.listTemplate = "106";
      ctx.listName = "{4CEEBDA9-E896-403F-B07F-DE16B64E8CA2}";
      ctx.view = "{67BF6D15-6B2E-49B7-91BE-8EF6236797AC}";
      ctx.listUrlDir = "/sites/rd_home/Lists/Community%20Events";
      ctx.HttpPath = "https://connect.gsk.com/sites/rd_home/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001";
      ctx.HttpRoot = "https://connect.gsk.com/sites/rd_home";
      ctx.imagesPath = "/_layouts/images/";
      ctx.PortalUrl = "";
      ctx.SendToLocationName = "";
      ctx.SendToLocationUrl = "";

          ctx.RecycleBinEnabled = 1;

      ctx.OfficialFileName = "";
      ctx.OfficialFileNames = "";
      ctx.WriteSecurity = "1";
      ctx.SiteTitle = "R\u0026D Home";
      ctx.ListTitle = "Community Events";
      if (ctx.PortalUrl == "") ctx.PortalUrl = null;
      ctx.displayFormUrl = "https://connect.gsk.com/sites/rd_home/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={4CEEBDA9-E896-403F-B07F-DE16B64E8CA2}";
      ctx.editFormUrl = "https://connect.gsk.com/sites/rd_home/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId={4CEEBDA9-E896-403F-B07F-DE16B64E8CA2}";
      ctx.isWebEditorPreview = 0;
      ctx.ctxId = 2751;
      ctx.isXslView = true;

      if (g_ViewIdToViewCounterMap["{67BF6D15-6B2E-49B7-91BE-8EF6236797AC}"] == null)
          g_ViewIdToViewCounterMap["{67BF6D15-6B2E-49B7-91BE-8EF6236797AC}"]= 2751;
      ctx.CurrentUserId = 28;

        ctx.ContentTypesEnabled = true;

      ctx2751 = ctx;
      g_ctxDict['ctx2751'] = ctx;
    </script>]]></xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>  


  <div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_Row"> 







<div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_Date"><xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@EventDate) ,1033 ,'dd MMM')" />
</div>

 <div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_Mid"><img src="/sites/rd_home/PublishingImages/RDHP/RDHP_Greater_than.gif" width="13" height="12" /></div>

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_Event_Date_div" CTXName="ctx2751" id="]]></xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="@ID" disable-output-escaping="yes" />

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[" Field="LinkTitle" Perm="0x7fffffffffffffff" EventType="0"><a href="https://connect.gsk.com/sites/rd_home/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={4CEEBDA9-E896-403F-B07F-DE16B64E8CA2}&amp;ID=]]></xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="@ID" disable-output-escaping="yes" />

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&amp;ContentTypeID=0x010200BA3C83EBA13243D1AEA8EBA290B005FB0080088C6F4532624AB6759DAF6AD8FB1E" onclick="EditLink2(this,2751);return false;" target="_self">]]></xsl:text>




   <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- if YOUR_STRING is greater than the MAXIMUM_LENGTH -->
                    <xsl:when test="string-length($RDHP_Title) &gt; 30" >
                        <!-- print out the truncated value followed by "..." -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($RDHP_Title,0, 30)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />...
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <!-- otherwise print out the whole, un-truncated string -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="$RDHP_Title" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>     

 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</a></div><div class="s4-ctx" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;"><span> </span><a onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;" title="Open Menu"></a><span> </span></div>]]></xsl:text>   

  </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>



        <xsl:if test="$CurPos = $LastRow">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_Row_btm"> 
    <div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_bottom_left"><a href="https://connect.gsk.com/sites/rd_home/Lists/Community%20Events/calendar.aspx"><img src="/sites/rd_home/PublishingImages/RDHP/RDHP_View_full_cal.jpg" alt="View full calendar" width="112" height="22" border="0" /></a></div>
    <div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_bottom_right"></div><div style="width:15px; float:left; padding-top:7px;"></div>
  </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

      <div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_Row_btm"> 
    <div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_bottom_left"><a href="mailto:jackie.a.staunton@gsk.com; cara.r.krikory@gsk.com?subject=New Event for RD Home Page"><img src="/sites/rd_home/PublishingImages/RDHP/RDHP_Add_new_event.jpg" alt="Add new event" width="109" height="25" border="0" /></a></div>
    <div class="RDHP_Events_Cal_bottom_right"></div>
    </div>]]></xsl:text>

            <!--
                Display all useable elements: 
                <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                    P:<xsl:value-of select="name()" /><br />
                    V:<xsl:value-of select="current()" /><br />
                </xsl:for-each>
            -->
        </xsl:if>
       </xsl:template>
```

I haven't used these in a while and I'm completely at a loss as to where to look to further debug and troubleshoot this.